# Batch file to create a folder in multiple other folders and assign NTFS Perms to it

Tags: permissions, batch-file, ntfs

I have a series of folders which receive .pdf files from paper scans made by staff at a photocopier. One folder per Business Unit on a Windows 2000 server, so:

```
Scan$  
    Unit 1\  
    Unit 2\  
    Unit 3\
```

What I'm trying to do is write a batch file to create a folder named:

'Temp area - files will be deleted after 14 days !'

and place it into each of the Unit 1,2,3 'root' folders to remind staff not to store data there long-term.  Once I have created that folder I need to set the NTFS perms, maybe with `icacls`, to only allow Domain Admins to access the folder I created, so staff cannot delete it.

I've written batch files before to create 'home' folders reading names from a .txt, eg `for /f %%a in (users.txt) do ..icacls \\filer\Personal$\Home\%%a /grant:r "Company\Domain Admins:(OI)(CI)F"`

I'm struggling with this issue, any help appreciated :-)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your examples (`for` and `icacls`) are promising. What, in particular, are you struggling with? Is it the creation of the new folders, or the locking down of permissions?

Comment: Hi Doug, so kinda both, the Unit folders exist, so I can place them in a .txt file then read them in MD the new folder then Icacl restrict the access. That's the theory !  But the practical is the struggle for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this with this simple script:

```
@ECHO off

SET _Path=\\unc\scan$
SET _FolderName=Temp area - files will be deleted after 14 days!

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%_Path%" /B /R /AD') DO (
    mkdir "%_Path%\%%a\%_FolderName%"
    icacls "%_Path%\%%a\%_FolderName%" <...>
)
```

### Breakdown

- `SET _Path=\\unc\scan$` sets a variable holding the path to the folder containing the `Unit 1`, `Unit 2`, `Unit 3` folders. Setting this in only one places makes it easier to change in the future
- `SET _FolderName=Temp area - files will be deleted after 14 days!` sets a variable holding the name of the folder you want to create and lock
- `dir "%_Path%" /B /AD` lists the subdirectories in the path you specified
- `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%_Path%" /B /R /AD') DO` will loop through the subdirectories
- `mkdir "%_Path%\%%a\%_FolderName%"` creates your new subdirectories using the folder name specified
- `icacls "%_Path%\%%a\%_FolderName%" <...>` will run your `icacls` to set the permissions. You'll have to replace `<...>` with whatever `/grant` or `/deny` permissions you want to set.

### References

- [For - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [For - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [iCacls - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)